# Unable to open .pptx file by using Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a .pptx file in my device storage. I'm trying to open this .pptx file using Intent.ACTION_VIEW. But I got an error that "No Activity found to handle Intent".

[error logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZu2u.png)

Here is my Code

```
file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path+"/emulated/0/Download/file.pptx")
uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.provider",file)
intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Well which app did you install on your Android device that can handle such files?

Comment: Post your error logcat here along code. It will be easy for peers to detect issues.

Comment: @blackapps did not install any apps. do I need to install any app to handle this?